# осортировать слова по алфавиту (с++)

Tags: c++, строки, сортировка

Вводится последовательность слов (обязательно string) до встречи слова "stop" (Количество слов НЕ более 10). Вывести в алфавитном порядке.

Что-то вообще нет понятия как из String'a слова достать.Может кто натолкнуть на путь истинный?Ток пожалуйста как можно проще.Без векторов, всяких замудрённых функций и.т.д

Comment: Добавте прмо в вопрос, что уже у вас получилось.

Comment: Чем в строке разделяются слова?

Comment: Желательно наверное через cin.слово ввёл и enter

Answer (score 1):

Как понимаете, Вам в любом случаи придётся пользоваться массивом, чтобы как-то хранить слова.

[Рабочий пример.](https://ideone.com/suGbGD)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string arr[11], word;

    int size = 0;
    while (cin >> word) {
        if (word == "stop") break;
        arr[size++] = word;  // Запись слова в массив
    }

    sort(arr, arr + size); // Сортируем 

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << arr[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, там просили "...Что-то вообще нет понятия как из String'a слова достать..." :)

Comment: Я, думаю, что исходный вопрос не корректен, и требует уточнения.

Comment: @entithat, а без векторов никак не реализуется?

Comment: @entithat, а с массивом как тогда?

Comment: @entithat всё, благодарю за наводку

Comment: @Sneikof, рад помочь :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    string s = "Has a strong desire to learn and explore new technologies " ;
    istringstream is(s);  // теперь строка в строковом потоке
    string  res;          
    while (is >> res && res != "stop")
        cout << res << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

если вам код не понятен, то рекомендую побольше читать, а чтобы сортировать, то в цикле `rez` нужно во что то хранить, или написать самому код сортировки.

Это был ответ на часть вопроса ("как из String'a слова достать"), если кому непонятно...